# Questrade.emit error

Tags: node.js

I am trying to use a [package](https://github.com/leanderlee/questrade) for Questrade which is a financial company. When I run my app.js file I get the error:

```
Error: Unhandled "error" event. ([object Object])
    at Questrade.emit (events.js:185:19)
```

Now I get the error is not handled but looking at the docs I can not find out where or how I should include error handling. I used just the code from the section below the install to see if I could get it to work and nope not working at all. I have tried adding it on and can't figure out the right place or how. I'm a bit lost after a few hours of pounding my head.

```
 // Wait to login
qt.on('ready', error, () => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
    }
  // Access your account here
  qt.getAccounts();
  qt.getBalances();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple, you have to add the `error` event to your file.

```
qt.on('error', function(err){
   console.log(err);
})
```

Also, while getting items, you can also have a callback function.

```
qt.on('ready',  () => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
    }
  // Access your account here
  qt.getAccounts(function(err, accounts){
     //handler
  });
  qt.getBalances(function(err, balances){
     //handler
  });
});
```

Comment: Your idea doesn't work, no matter what way I try to include error it fails. It breaks even sooner so I can't even get at the error I am having. I tried with and without quotes, it fails each time. Says error is not defined, so unless this package is majorly different from everything else I have used, I should not have to declare the error variable in a function. The error handling for the get accounts and balances should work fine. No matter what I do I get the same error and it doesn't tell me what line the issue is with just references the package's events.js file.

Comment: very interesting @SeaitManageit can you try it like this ? 'qt.on('ready',  (err) => {})' with the error inside the parameter

Comment: I tried that and has the same error in the console.

Comment: can you add `.on('error)` right after qt, like this. `qt.on('ready', () =>).on('error', function(err){})` . I have even checked the index.js file from github, if you search for keyword *error* you will there are 4 there with self.emit. I don't know why it doesn't work

Comment: Here is my entire app.js file other than my API which I removed for security.

https://plnkr.co/edit/To8T8JniKRj7Cxl3BRN9?p=info

Comment: Realized I put the .on('error') you said in the wrong place on that plunk. Could not figure out what your example meant because I tried it how you have it and same error

Comment: No, the ) in front of the .on('error') caused an issue so I added {} before and still issues. I am lost..

Comment: I moved the call back and changed it to a es5 callback and it worked. Maybe the es6 syntax fails? IDK but now onto the next error it throws..wonder when that is..

Comment: it does, how did *I* make that mistake.. this node module uses EventEmitter from events npm, their syntax is not compatible with with es6.

Comment: see this link for more info on how events work, you'll understand better why it can't be combined with es6 @SeaitManageit https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_event_emitter.htm

Comment: can you set it answered @SeaitManageit